# Table scroll com posição da rolagem conforme data

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma `table` com uma lista de aniversários. Uso uma div que deixa ela `scroll` com tamanho horizontal fixado. Gostaria que a rolagem da tabela fosse na posição da data atual. Como nessa foto abaixo:

Supondo que hoje fosse o dia 20.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/4632/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro a fazer isso utilizando **jquery**, segue uma alternativa de solução, pego o dia atual e utilizo o `.animate()` para scrollar até o respectivo elemento do [seletor](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), o `-140` é só para centralizar a data na visualização.

Caso tu queira para o dia atual basta comentar o `var day = 17;` e descomentar o `var day = d.getDate();`. Espero que ajude.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  //var day = d.getDate();
  var day = 17;
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $('#table-scroll').animate({
    scrollTop: $('td:contains("' + day + '")').offset().top - 140
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
#table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#table-scroll {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#table-wrapper table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso aí. Valeu amigo